# List vs ArrayList vs Vector

Tags: java, list, arraylist, vector

Хочу узнать в чём глобальная разница между ArrayList и Vector. Я поискал и нашёл только информацию о том,что вектор синхронизирован ( с чем?). Я не очень понял. Также не понимаю чем принципиальная разница List от ArrayList. Буду рад вашим пояснениям

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vector в отличии от ArrayList потокобезопасен, то есть все интерфейсные методы помечены модификатором synchronized, получается что с ним может работать только один поток, поскольку на весь вектор один единственный монитор.Это сказывается на производительности, поэтому рекомендуется работать с ArrayList, которым можешь управлять в потоках как твоей душе угодно, в отличии от Vector.

List это интерфейс который и реализует Vector и ArrayList

Comment: такой вопрос. Если я хочу работать с листом как с массивом, если какой-нибудь способ кроме .get(number). Возможно я не прав, но я думаю, что пробегается по всем элементам Листа.
Если я хочу получить элемент №12222, то он пробегает все 12222 ячейки?

Comment: @WBLord если `ArrayList`, то нет, если `LinkedList`, то да.

Comment: В ArrayList спрятан обычный массив, так что доступ к элементам идет за константное время.Так что с ним можешь работать и не переживать, тем более за его увеличение отвечает нативный метод System.arraycopy

Answer (score 1):

[List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) - это [абстрактный тип данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85). [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) - конкретная реализация этого типа на базе массива. [Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) - это коллекция из древних времён Java, сохранённая в стандартной библиотеке для того, чтобы старый код мог работать на новых JVM.

Этот вопрос уже много раз задавался на Stackoverflow, и есть множество статей в Интернете на эту тему, но лучше всего это объясняется в любом учебнике.

Answer (score 1):

Кроме синхронизации и степени древности Vector и ArrayList отличаются также размером увеличения подкапотного массива. В ArrayList массив увеличивается в 1,5 раза. В Vector в 2.